# Can I roll back WP Install but keep my newer database?

Tags: backup

My transition to 4.6.1 has been hellish and I'd like to go back until I have time to code my way round the issues it causes.

The trouble is I've had the site live for a day and user interactions have changed the database. I'd like to keep the new database and roll back the WP install to my previous version by simply restoring my compressed root folder back to where it was and save the new one for another day.

In testing this locally it seemed to work absolutely fine but am I setting myself up for a big future headache for when it comes time to update again? Often when it seems too simple - it is....

Comment: You're making things worse.

Comment: OK @Nabil Kadimi - would you care to expand at all? I'm more interested in why and how I can mitigate

Comment: What you want to do is unlikely to fix the issues you have, the result is unpredictable. What you should do is to know what causes the issues and fix them.

Comment: I may be repeating my self, the result is **unpredictable**.

Comment: Yeah... I know :( The issue is that there's some conflict somewhere between 2 of my *key* plugins in 4.6.1. A few front facing pages now take over 10 minutes to load (with no debug errors) and the solution means redesigning the plugin theme, which is now structured in a totally different way to before. There's nearly 3 years of slow gradual work in there so I can't see me getting it back in less than 2 weeks. I guess I'm damned either way...

Comment: What ever you try, don't forget to take backup first! So that if outcomes don't come as per your expectation you can roll back. IMHO best option will be to make sub domain of your live project and do all experiments on that, so live project don't get disturb even for a single second. When your experiments will get success then you can turn your sub-domain in original domain itself (So that you don't have to repeat all process in original domain also).

Comment: As a more easier option take backup of your new database. Then downgrade wordpress and you must now have old database. Now your changes in new db must be in some table (not all). Example: If after upgrade changes has been made in pages/post then you just need to update `wp_post` table, so just copy wp_post table from backup and import it in old db and you will get your desired db.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately as I have a large number of users the number of interactions and changes to the database would mean a lot of work - there's probably over 100 extra CPTs added not to mention the number of comments, changed preferences, profile data... It would be a tough ask.

Comment: You should investigate slow SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To roll back your WordPress version you will need to download the version of WordPress you want to roll back to and also use FTP client.

Firstly, it is important to never copy over your 'wp-content' directory or the 'wp-config.php' file.

1. Using your FTP client connect to your website server and locate the directory with your WordPress files (wp-admin, wp-content, etc.).
2. Create a new directory labelled with the WP version you are downgrading from, for example 'wp_4.6.1'.
3. Using the FTP client move all WordPress directories and files (other than the 'wp-content' directory and the 'wp-config.php' file) in to the directory you just created. You can leave any other directories and files that are noth related to WordPress.
4. On your computer, unzip the WordPress version you want to rollback to. Using your FTP client, (other than the 'wp-content' directory) upload all files you just extracted locally.
5. Wait for all files to upload and then visit your WordPress admin. You should be prompted to update your WordPress database. Click on 'Update WordPress Database' and then click continue to login.

You should have rolled back your version of WordPress now.

Answer (score 0):

With Database:

I think you should save all tables (except WP_OPTIONS) from current database, then install new site, and replace all tables (except WP_OPTIONS).

p.s.  If you use multisite, then you need not only wp_options,but other tables too: WP_BLOGS, WP_SITES etc..

Answer (score 0):

you can do the rollback manually by saving exporting the old DB , install the old Wordpress into a new folder , import the old DB into this new version. And you are done .

Or you can use this plugin it can help you to rollback the Wordpress or Plugins  :
[Wp Rollback](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rollback/)

Comment: This is the opposite of what I need to do - the database *must* be the new database as I need to keep my users actions.